# Dota 2 problems

Tags: 13.04

I new at Linux, and I just got Ubuntu 13.04 and I have been trying to play Dota and:

1. I found that the loading screen does not show up, but the standard Valve video plays.
2. I get a black screen, then the Dota 2 menu, if I do a lobby match with bots it shows a black screen and Dota closes.

My friend suggested updating Mesa, whatever that is, how do I do that? Is that the solution? I have a 64-bit PC, and my friend made me try running: `sudo apt-get install ia32-ilbs`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing video card drivers. Search for additional drivers in the dash, and then launch the application and install the ones for the video card marked recommended.

Comment: it says no propietary drivers are in use